# What is the FMS Bridge Visual 28R approach at SFO?

Tags: fms, sfo, iaps, visual-approaches

I've read that SFO has a specialized FMS Bridge Visual approach to 28R that is not published but instead is custom tailored for specific operators. What exactly is this approach and how does it work? When is it assigned, and what advantage does it have over other visual approaches to runway 28R?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ***FMS Bridge Visual Approach 28R*** is a version of the ***Quiet Bridge Visual Approach 28R*** which is coded with GPS coordinates and can be included in an FMS database for approved operators.  This allows the procedure to be used when the SFO 
VOR is out of service, and also gives ATC additional flexibility by allowing them to clear pilots direct to any of the fixes without needing to intercept the radial on the standard arrival.

The pilot must either tell ATC that they can accept it verbally, or include ***FMS28R ABLE*** in the remarks of their flight plan so that they know that the flight is capable of flying the approach.

Answer (score 5):

> [image]
> Source: [stilllearningtofly.org](https://www.stilllearningtofly.org/investigating-the-investigations/1662-2/)

The FMS bridge visual is an RNAV charted visual approach to 28R that keeps aircraft offset to the north of the 28R localizer until they’re near the San Mateo bridge. This allows a little bit more space between aircraft that are pairing up on final. Procedurally it’s no different than the tipp toe visual for 28R/L. Charted visuals allow the controllers to clear an aircraft for the approach once they have a charted landmark or the airport in sight. Vs a standard visual where the pilot must have the airport in sight. We will automatically assign the FMS to most airliner traffic inbound from the East over ARCHI. GA or some foreign carriers will get the quiet bridge visual or the ILS.

Comment: Do you have a bigger image?

Comment: I tried to upload a bigger image but it said it was too big. This is all I could get to work. I’m on my phone too, which might be the problem.

Comment: I added a bigger one I found, which looks like the one you found, if not, let me know. Also looks like it's a company procedure, not one published by the FAA, correct? This agrees with the company's name on the plate, and the older answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding a better picture! I’m not a pilot, so I’m not sure how the company approaches work. I’ve heard that only the airlines that buy it are able to do the FMS. I’m not sure if United designed it and sold it to others. Most major airlines have it, it’s not exclusive to 1. But foreign / smaller airlines and GA will ask for the quiet bridge.

Comment: Murph - welcome to Av.SE!  Always good to have controllers join us here to share your perspectives on various topics.  Please hang around!

Comment: Ralph J-  Thanks!  I didn’t know I let it slip that I was a controllers.  This is a cool place to ask questions and get answers!